# How much traffic can my web server cope with before crashing?

Tags: php, apache, max, visitors

Simple question, I realise it depends on many things like page load times, page size, are static resources served from a content network blah blah blah. So let's keep it simple.

If I have a CentOS box single core 1.3 Ghz (PHP) with 8GB ram, and page loads times are 1 second and the total non cached file size of a page is 70KB how many visitors can my server handle before server busy message show up ?

At the moment 1 of our sites might have up to 20 users at any time, if that number was 1000 would the server cope with it ?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a load testing tool and find out?

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html

Comment: Cool I knew something like that must exist but no one ever told me before :) - I figured there may be na industry secret `rule of thumb` to this.